# Visual studio removes semicolon on re intend

Tags: visual-studio

I am using VueJS and I want to use the shorthand way:

```
<!-- full syntax -->
<a v-bind:href="url"></a>

<!-- shorthand -->
<a :href="url"></a>
```

but when I re-indent the html, it removes the semicolon. How I can disable this?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you running? Because I see this: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1880541